# gradle - reference in external jar file

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

i have a problem in using  external jar file . My project layout:

```
 -gradleproject     
   -A(project)
     -src
       -a.java
   -B(project)
   -build
   -libs
     -custom.jar
   -src
   -build.gradle
   -settings
```

custom.jar(java source)

```
 public class custom{
    public String custom() {
        return "custom!!";
    }
}
```

a.java

```
 package gradleproject;
 public class a{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        custom cus = new custom();
        System.out.println("custom file: "+cus);
    }
}
```

I want to use the custom.jar file in a.java

tried methods like this, but not resolved.

```
 a/build.gradle
 dependencies{
    compile files('libs/custom.jar')
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include : ['*.jar'])
    runtime fileTree(dir: 'libs', include : '*.jar')
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is probably due to the fact that gradle is looking for your library file relative to your current project, which is A.  If you were to do something in a/build.gradle like the following:

```
dependencies {
    compile files("${rootDir}/libs/custom.jar")
}
```

does that work?  This is assuming that your root directory is the gradleproject folder, if not you can always use ../libs/custom.jar to find the custom jar.